# Removing the common characters between two character ARRAYS

Tags: java, arrays

This is for a class, so we have some pretty particular constraints.
We cannot use ArrayList, and the manipulation must be with arrays.

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
char[] firstArray = new char[]{'a','b'};
char[] secondArray = new char[]{'b','b','c',};
```

I want to return the arrays as:

```
 firstArray = [a];
 secondArray = [b,c];
```

Note that secondArray still returns a char 'b', because it contains two but only shares one with firstArray.

How would I do this?
I'm pretty new to coding so an explanation is appreciation
Thanks

Comment: Are the arrays guaranteed to be sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Yes they could be sorted alphabetically. its not guaranteed but that would just mean using the sort() method correct?

Comment: Please ask more specific questions. If you take a class in java, you porbably discussed some concepts before your prof/teacher gave you this exercise. Try to use those concepts to solve the problem (most probably loops). If you have specific questions to loops, please ask those instead.

Comment: @Turing85 I think bare "idownvotedbecau.se' links [are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356051/5212501)

Comment: @LordFarquaad I diagree with the post you linked. We can continue the discussion in [chat] if you like.

Comment: @Turing85 When I asked the question I was hoping for an easy couple lines. If that's not the case I'll think my way through working with some messy loops and what not.

Thank you for the advice nontheless.

Comment: @Elaredo The convention for asking questions on SO is to include what you have tried, example code, etc. Respectfully, we aren't here to do homework for people. We *are*, however, here to help write cleaner and/or more optimized code, help you understand why code you have written isn't working as intended, etc.  To get you started, think about how you could compare the arrays to one another and remove elements that won't be in your final answer. If you get some code written and get stuck, feel free to ask a new question with code samples and results achieved.

Comment: @Bryan "*We are, however, here to help write cleaner... code*" - No. That is what [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for.

Comment: @Bryan Very much understood. I had assumed that my question was relaively easy to answer with a single method or what not. I wasn't expecting someone to write me an entire block of code answering my homework.

Comment: @Turing85 I did not know that existed... now I do! Can't edit my previous comment but this is noted.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is use a nested loop (2 levels) to traverse through the arrays to see if they have duplicates.  When you encounter a duplicate, increment a counter and change the elements to some character that you want to use as a flag so it's not used in the result.

Once you are done with that, you can recreate new arrays that are smaller than the original arrays based on the counter

```
char[] newFirstArray = new char[firstArray.length - counter];
char[] newSecondArray = new char[secondArray.length - counter];
```

Then traverse through the original arrays and copy the remaining good characters into the new arrays.

Comment: I used a similar method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Elaredo Kindly check my answer, if it helped guide you to your solution.

Answer (score -1):

i created a function which is some coplicated for you but may be you can understand easily, and you should import `import java.util.*;` to use it:

function:-

```
ArrayList<char[]> results(char[] a, char[] b) {
    ArrayList<Character> res1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Character> res2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        res1.add(a[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        res2.add(b[i]);
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> a_commons = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> b_commons = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            if (res1.get(i).equals(res2.get(j))) {
                a_commons.add(i);
                b_commons.add(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(a_commons, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Collections.sort(b_commons, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (int common_number : a_commons) {
        res1.remove(common_number);
    }

    for (int common_number : b_commons) {
        res2.remove(common_number);
    }

    char[] a_res = new char[res1.size()];
    char[] b_res = new char[res2.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < res1.size(); i++) {
        a_res[i] = res1.get(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < res2.size(); i++) {
        b_res[i] = res2.get(i);
    }

    ArrayList<char[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(a_res);
    result.add(b_res);
    return result;
}
```

using it:-

```
char[] a = new char[]{'a','b'};
char[] b = new char[]{'b','b', 'c', 'a'};

ArrayList<char[]> res = results(a,b);

char[] a_RESULT = res.get(0);
char[] b_RESULT = res.get(1);
```

Comment: read the answer completely and after that you can say your comments if you see i used just for finding the result and the result is not arraylist.

Comment: I would ask that you read the OP's question.  'We cannot use ArrayList, and the manipulation must be with arrays.'